# Change font of datepicker dialog in android by coding not in xml

Tags: android

How to change font of date picker dialog by coding in android not in xml file 
my code is below

```
public void select_date() {
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Get_a_Quote.this.getParent(),
                dateset, Integer.parseInt(DateFormat
                        .format("yyyy", cal).toString()), cal
                        .get(Calendar.MONTH), cal
                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 <style name="DatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@font/roboto</item>
    </style>
```

Hope this will help to you too.